# Android - Soundpool do not play all sounds with many apps in the background.

Tags: android, background, soundpool

I'm making a game with a lot of sounds and I use Soundpool to play them. In almost every sound I make a new Thread to not load to much in the main UI thread. Like this:

```
public void playSatelliteWinning(final Boolean isSound) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (isSound && !satelliteIsPlaying) {
                satelliteIsPlaying = true;
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        play(satelliteWinning);
                    }
                }, 100);
                satelliteIsPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

But when I'm running a lot of other apps on my mobile many sounds do not play in my game. When I kill all apps running on my mobile and then start my game, there are no problem with the sounds.
Seems like some sort of lack of memory or something. Do anyone have a similar problem or a fix for this? Any ideas? Thanks!

I run my game on a Nexus 5X, Android 6.0

Comment: For some reason it seems that it is Candy Crush Soda that causes this problem. If I kill Candy Crush Soda and run a lot of other apps in the background there are no problems with my sounds.

Answer (score 1):

The default thread pool size is 5, i assume that's what's blocking you.
I think you should create a SoundManager.

```
public class SoundManager {

    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_MENU_BTN         = 0;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_WIN              = 1;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_LOOSE            = 2;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_DRAW             = 3;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK1            = 4;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK2            = 5;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_OUT_OF_TIME      = 6;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_HISCORE          = 7;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_CORRECT_LETTER   = 8;

    public static boolean isSoundTurnedOff;

    private static SoundManager mSoundManager;

    private SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private SparseArray <Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private AudioManager  mAudioManager;

    public static final int maxSounds = 4;

    public static SoundManager getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (mSoundManager == null){
            mSoundManager = new SoundManager(context);
        }

        return mSoundManager;
   }

    public SoundManager(Context mContext)
    {
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(maxSounds, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

//        mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
//            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,int status) {
//               loaded = true;
//            }
//        });

        mSoundPoolMap = new SparseArray<Integer>(); 
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_MENU_BTN, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.menubutton, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_WIN, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.win, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_LOOSE, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.lose, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK1, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.tick_0, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK2, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.tick_1, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_OUT_OF_TIME, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.out_of_time, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_HISCORE, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.personal_highscore, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_CORRECT_LETTER, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.correct_letter, 1));

        // testing simultaneous playing
        int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(0), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 20, 1f); 
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 2, 1f);
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(2), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);


    } 

    public void playSound(int index) { 
        if (isSoundTurnedOff)
            return;

         int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
         mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
    }

    public static void clear()
    {
        if (mSoundManager != null){
            mSoundManager.mSoundPool = null; 
            mSoundManager.mAudioManager = null;
            mSoundManager.mSoundPoolMap = null;
        }
        mSoundManager = null;
    }
}
```

you can add a method to play a specific sound, like

```
  public void playSound(SoundsEnum enum){
        // play the sound with that value
    }
```

Comment: Ok! Great, I will try this out! I will accept your answer if it works fine! :) Thanks!

Comment: Humm... I tried it out with just one button click sound. It plays the sound only 2 times, then there is no sound any more. :( I only run my game on the mobile right now. No apps in the background.

Comment: Strange, i still have the issue, when I close my app and open it again, some sounds are not playing.

Comment: Same here. I try to load 8 sounds In the SoundPool then play them one by one spaced in time, and it's only playing 4 or 5. For the rest, load() returns 0